# Numpy: np.select for 1-D arrays given scalar condlist

Tags: python, performance, numpy

I'm trying to get something like this:

```
def choozer(my_1D_array):
    newArray = np.zeros((len(my_1D_array), 5))
    for x in enumerate(my_1D_array):
        if x[1]<3:
            y = np.array([1,1,1,1,1]) #the y's can be any array of random values
        elif 3<=x[1]<=5:
            y = np.array([2,2,2,2,2])# don't need to be repeated
        elif x[1]>5:
            y = np.array([3,3,3,3,3])
        newArray[x[0]] = y
    return newArray
```

This *works*...but seems very roundabout to me, and efficiency is important with my application. So i got the idea to compare it with [np.select](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html):

```
def np_choozer(my_1D_array):
    condlist = [my_1D_array<3, 
                np.logical_and((3<=my_1D_array),(my_1D_array<=5)), 
                my_1D_array>5]
    choicelist = [np.array([1,1,1,1,1]),
                  np.array([2,2,2,2,2]),
                  np.array([3,3,3,3,3])]
    return np.select(condlist, choicelist)
```

...but no dice. It returns choicelist values on axis 1. Is there a better way to do a general version of my above problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry. I really should get better at writing examples. The `y` arrays can be anything. In my case, they'd be `1`'s and `0`'s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`np_choozer` gives the correct result for `my_1D_array.reshape(-1,1)`. Thanks for your help, guys...though i'm still curious to see if anyone else can come up with a better way.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it can be written more nicely with `np.select`, but you can always do:

```
newArray = np.zeros(my_1D_array.shape + (5,))
newArray[np.where(my_1D_array < 3)] = 1
newArray[np.where((my_1D_array >= 3) & (my_1D_array <= 5)] = 2
newArray[np.where(my_1D_array > 5)] = 3
```

An example:

```
>>> a = np.random.rand(10) * 10
>>> b = np.empty(a.shape + (5,))
>>> b[np.where(a < 3)] = 1
>>> b[np.where((a >= 3) & (a <= 5))] = 2
>>> b[np.where(a > 5)] = 3
>>> b
array([[ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 3.,  3.,  3.,  3.,  3.],
       [ 2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  2.],
       [ 3.,  3.,  3.,  3.,  3.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 3.,  3.,  3.,  3.,  3.],
       [ 3.,  3.,  3.,  3.,  3.],
       [ 3.,  3.,  3.,  3.,  3.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 3.,  3.,  3.,  3.,  3.]])
```

---

**EDIT** The code above is taking advantage of broadcasting in the assignments, but the `1`, `2` and `3` can be replaced by a 5 element list or array. With the same `a` and `b` as the example above:

```
>>> b[np.where(a < 3)] = np.arange(5)
>>> b[np.where((a >= 3) & (a <= 5))] = np.arange(5) + 10
>>> b[np.where(a > 5)] = np.arange(5) + 20
>>> b
array([[  0.,   1.,   2.,   3.,   4.],
       [ 20.,  21.,  22.,  23.,  24.],
       [ 10.,  11.,  12.,  13.,  14.],
       [ 20.,  21.,  22.,  23.,  24.],
       [  0.,   1.,   2.,   3.,   4.],
       [ 20.,  21.,  22.,  23.,  24.],
       [ 20.,  21.,  22.,  23.,  24.],
       [ 20.,  21.,  22.,  23.,  24.],
       [  0.,   1.,   2.,   3.,   4.],
       [ 20.,  21.,  22.,  23.,  24.]])
```

Comment: Thanks, but can you think of a more general case with np.where? I just used repeating ints because i'm lazy; but in reality, the `y`'s would be a random assortment of ints (one's and zeroes in my case).

Answer (score 0):

This,

```
import numpy as np

a = np.arange(10)

one = np.ones((5,a.shape[0]))
two = 2 * one
thr = 3 * one

def choozer(a):
    condlist = [a<3, np.logical_and((3<=a),(a<=5)), a>5]
    choicelist = [one,two,thr]
    return np.select(condlist, choicelist).T

print choozer(a)
```

gives this,

```
[[ 1.  1.  1.  1.  1.]
 [ 1.  1.  1.  1.  1.]
 [ 1.  1.  1.  1.  1.]
 [ 2.  2.  2.  2.  2.]
 [ 2.  2.  2.  2.  2.]
 [ 2.  2.  2.  2.  2.]
 [ 3.  3.  3.  3.  3.]
 [ 3.  3.  3.  3.  3.]
 [ 3.  3.  3.  3.  3.]
 [ 3.  3.  3.  3.  3.]]
```

Comment: Thanks, but can you think of a more general case? I just used repeating ints because i'm lazy; but in reality, the y's would be a random assortment of ints (one's and zeroes in my case).